# Rails command line not found when installed with RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

After installing RVM, I have installed Ruby 1.8.7 then Rails 3.
When I do `which rails` I get `/Users/davidbenhamou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/bin/rails`.
But when I do `rails -v` I get `-bash: /usr/bin/rails: No such file or directory`

Why is Rails not working?
Note: I have followed all steps from RVM website and Ruby command line work fine (`ruby -v`).

Comment: I think you have to reinstall all gems for every RVM Ruby.

Comment: usually it works for me... you may want to restart the shell... also, don't do `sudo gem install <gem_name>` (don't use `sudo`)

Comment: closing the terminal and reopening works for me even though i have the run script checked in my terminal preferences

Answer (score 14):

To see the rubies you have installed:

```
rvm list rubies
```

And you'll see something like this:

```
   ree-1.8.7-2011.03 [ i686 ]
*  ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p0 [ x86_64  ] 
=> ruby-1.9.3-p125 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf [ x86_64 ]
```

To use a specific one:

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p125
```

then if you do `ruby --version`, you'll see:

```
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin10.7.0]
```

In *each* of these rubies you need to install all the gems you want to use. The way I do it is actually by using Bundler to install all the gems for a project. But for the simple case here, just do:

```
rvm all do gem install rails
```

This will install the rails gem in *all* your ruby versions. To install to a particular one, use:

```
rvm ruby-1.9.3-p125  do gem install rails
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It never crossed my mind I had to re-install rails for every ruby version I had. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

after you installed RVM and after you set the default Ruby version in RVM, you need to re-install all ruby gems, e.g.

gem install rails

you need to install those gems as the user, not as root.

Because from now on RVM will keep track of all installed gems by the ruby version which was used to install them!