# Could not find RubyGem railties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I try to create new app with "rails new" command however getting this error:

```
'report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem railties (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:244:in 'activate_dep'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:236:in `activate'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1307:in `gem'
 from /usr/local/bin/rails:18
```

Any idea why?

by the way I am working on Ubuntu

```
gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***
```

it is empty but I installed rails just before

Comment: Can you please run the following in terminal and output it here?

gem list

Comment: Well I'd try `gem install rails` and see where that gets you first.

Comment: You installed ruby from ubuntu repo? Might be you try install gems into /usr without sudo, and get errors. I recommend to you install RVM.

Comment: It looks like you're operating on an empty list of gems. You'll need to install Rails before trying to use it.

Comment: I installed rails and ruby with RVM however there was an early ruby installation and I delete it after RVM installation. In addition I execute gem install rails and it install all the gemss needed but I think system cannot find the necessary gem or rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install RVM (I don't know it is the best solution but it works) then use such rails commands like `rvmsudo rails new` or such. I use rails and ruby command with including rvm or rvmsudo phase and all of them start to work.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the issue before.The solution is :
you must use comand ***`gem install rails`***, not ***`sudo gem install rails`***.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and found the following solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713872/rails-command-line-not-found-when-installed-with-rvm) which was mentioned [here](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4003220). Hope it helps

After you installed RVM and after you set the default Ruby version in RVM, you need to re-install all ruby gems, e.g.

gem install rails

you need to install those gems as the user, not as root.

Because from now on RVM will keep track of all installed gems by the ruby version which was used to install them!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple Ruby installations on your system? Maybe you have installed some package (like Heroku with full installation) and you are using the 'new' Ruby installation. I have uninstalled the last Ruby and everything seems to be fine.

**Edit:** Not everything is fine... yet. Under Windows you will have to edit Heroku.bat (in your Program Files/Heroku path) and change the path to Ruby installation folder.

Answer (score -1):

Install rvm and try it again to install rails
RVM provides a very great way to manage your gems in Gemsets 
for multible ruby installations.

On the offizial rvm site is a installation tutorial

http://beginrescueend.com/